# HTML elements load in wrong position with 3G

Tags: html, django, loading, 3g

I have a website written in django/html. It works perfectly on computers, with cable internet, but it loads wrong when loaded from a mobile network (I used 3G). The strange is, this site is the exact copy of another one that I'm upgrading, and all I did was remove one picture, and add two others instead, and the original site works perfectly in 3G network. Here are the links to test it:

Original: http://www.creativeselector.hu

Wrong one: http://worker.creativeselector2-hrd.appspot.com

The sites are in Hungarian, don't be frightened by that :D The error happens at the top right part of the white center. The two images (red and orange) slip towards up and right, and the facebook module slips up. Do you have any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: I have troubles you describe when accessing it with my desktop. Certainly problem of CSS

Comment: Have same problem on Desktop, Firefox.

Comment: Thanks guys, it really was CSS problem. The div containing the two images was for some reason very wide, I made it smaller, and rearranged the images, and now it's fine on my mobile as well as on my computer. Thanks again!